# C# Crop & resize large images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, image-resizing

I got some very large building drawings, sometimes 22466x3999 with a bit depth of 24, or even larger.
I need to be able to resize these to smaller versions, and to be able to cut out sections of the image to smaller images.

I have been using the following code to resize the images, which I found [here](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/c-resize-image-while):

```
       public static void ResizeImage(string OriginalFile, string NewFile, int NewWidth, int MaxHeight, bool OnlyResizeIfWider)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OriginalFile);
            if (OnlyResizeIfWider)
            {
                if (FullsizeImage.Width <= NewWidth)
                {
                    NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width;
                }
            }
            int NewHeight = FullsizeImage.Height * NewWidth / FullsizeImage.Width;
            if (NewHeight > MaxHeight)
            {
                NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width * MaxHeight / FullsizeImage.Height;
                NewHeight = MaxHeight;
            }
            System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewWidth, NewHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            FullsizeImage.Dispose();
            NewImage.Save(NewFile);
        }
```

And this code to crop the images:

```
public static MemoryStream CropToStream(string path, int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) return null;
            Rectangle fromRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path, true))
            {
                Bitmap target = new Bitmap(fromRectangle.Width, fromRectangle.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                {
                    Rectangle croppedImageDimentions = new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height);
                    g.DrawImage(image, croppedImageDimentions, fromRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                target.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
                stream.Position = 0;
                return stream;
            }
        }
```

My problem is that i get a *Sytem.OutOfMemoryException* when I try to resize the image, and that's because I can't load the full image in to FullsizeImage.

So what I would like to know, how do I resize an image without loading the entire image into memory?

Comment: This is not a programming solution but you could try increasing the *virtual memory* size of your machine and see.

Comment: You should be working with LockBits for such image sizes

Comment: @Kurubaran I tried to increase the memory size, which didn't work, and I don't think its the correct solution for a webproject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are chances the `OutOfMemoryException` is not because of the size of the images, but because you don't dispose all the disposables classes correctly :

- `Bitmap target`
- `MemoryStream stream`
- `System.Drawing.Image NewImage`

are not disposed as they should. You should add a `using()` statement around them.

If you really encounter this error with just one image, then you should consider switch your project to x64. A 22466x3999 picture means 225Mb in memory, I think it shouldn't be an issue for x86. (so try to dispose your objects first).

Last but not least, [Magick.Net](https://magick.codeplex.com/) is very efficient about resizing / cropping large pictures.

Comment: Thank you, I will add `using()` to the Fullsizeimage and the other places. I did try Magick.Net, but I couldn't get it to work, but i'll give it a try if this doesn't help.

Comment: Image Magick.Net must be the way to go, because adding using's still returned a `OutOfMemoryException`. And if Image Magick.Net won't work, i'm going to make a separate service which handles all the image resizing and cropping..

Comment: Even on large 64bit system you can't create Bitmaps of arbitrary sizes. If he needs to work with really large Bitmaps I'm afraid that using a 3rd party lib is the best option..

Comment: I feel like I need to do a followup on this issue, after adding a couple of usings, it ended up working. I think you were right, I was using the method multiple times after each other, and at some point I would get the exception. So thank you! Another problem might have been that its a web-app, so the memory might be limited by the IIS memory cap.

Answer (score 1):

You can also force .Net to read the image directly from disk and stop memory caching.

Use

`sourceBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(sourceFileStream, false, false);`

Instead of

`...System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OriginalFile);`

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47424918/887092